# Display CPT list page (archive) with category term on slug

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type, taxonomy, slug

I have the CPT (Custom Post Type) "news".
In the "category" taxonomy I have "food" and "health".

The archive page is accessed via the url:

- [www.mysite.com/news](http://www.mysite.com/news)

Is there any way to show "news" by categories? Ex:

- [www.mysite.com/food/news](http://www.mysite.com/food/news)
- [www.mysite.com/health/news](http://www.mysite.com/health/news)

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You could *technically* achieve this, but it's probably better to do `/news/term` as that URL, from an SEO perspective, is more meaningful.

Comment: One way or another, is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

In that link I found the following solution:

---

The solution for me had three parts. In my case the post type is called trainings.

1. Add `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'trainings/%cat%')` to the
   `register_post_type` function.
2. Change the slug to have a dynamic
3. category. "Listen" to the new dynamic URL and load the appropriate template.

So here is how to change the permalink dynamically for a given post type. Add to `functions.php`:

```
function vx_soon_training_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $id );
    if ( is_object( $post ) ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'training_cat' );
        if ( $terms ) {
            return str_replace( '%cat%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link );
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'vx_soon_training_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

...and this is how to load the appropriate template on the new dynamic URL. Add to `functions.php`:

```
function archive_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^training/(.*)/(.*)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=trainings&name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
    //flush_rewrite_rules(); // use only once
}

add_action( 'init', 'archive_rewrite_rules' );
```

Thats it! Remember to refresh the permalinks by saving the permalinks again in de backend. Or use the `flush_rewrite_rules()` function.

---

But I have a question that I couldn't do there:

This part:

Add `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'trainings/%cat%')` to the `register_post_type` function.

where do I do that? Or is this already embedded in the later code?

Comment: I added this code (via Code Snippet plugin) because I read that it is not good practice to edit directly in functions.php. I just changed "trainings" to "news". Did not work. :( Please someone help me!!!!